# How to populate one entry widget based on what you type in another entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have two Entry fields, one for a user to enter number and the second one is for displaying the square of the number entered. The approach I would like is that when the user starts typing in the number in the first widget, the second widget should be updated with the corresponding square of the number being typed in the first widget.

Here is my GUI

[image: Here is my GUI]

Now this is my code but it is not working as I expect. Please help me understand how to go about this problem without involving user of a button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
def keyPressed(event):
    #key = entry.get(event.char)
    key=entry.get()
    if key.isdigit():
       ans_txt.delete(0, END)
       ans_txt.insert(0,key)
       print(key, " success")
    else:
        print("fail")
app=Tk()
app.geometry("400x350")

ent_lbl=Label(app, text="NUMBER: ", padx=3, pady=3)
ent_lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
entry = tk.Entry(width=15)
entry.bind("<Key>", keyPressed)
entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)

ans_lbl=Label(app, text="SQUARE: ", padx=3, pady=3)
ans_lbl.grid(column=0, row=20)
ans_txt=tk.Entry(app, width=15)
ans_txt.grid(column=1, row=20)


app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like you already have code to do what you want. What is this code doing and  how is it different from what you want?

Comment: Thanks Bryan Oakley for your comprehensive explanation. I now understand how to go about the this. Am grateful.

Comment: I don't understand your response. I just asked a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `.trace` method of the `Entry` widget. You can catch the "writing" event with the `trace` method and you can call a callback function with that method. Doc of `trace`: http://mgltools.scripps.edu/api/DejaVu/Tkinter.Variable-class.html

Furthermore you has to use the `IntVar()` to show (and calculate) the numbers in the resul `Entry` widget. Doc of `IntVar`: http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.IntVar-class.html

**Complete code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.geometry("400x350")

input_var = tk.IntVar()
Label(app, text="NUMBER: ", padx=3, pady=3).grid(column=0, row=0)
input_entry = tk.Entry(width=15, textvariable=input_var)
input_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)

result_var = tk.IntVar()
Label(app, text="SQUARE: ", padx=3, pady=3).grid(column=0, row=20)
output_entry = tk.Entry(app, width=15, textvariable=result_var)
output_entry.grid(column=1, row=20)


def key_pressed(name, index, mode):
    output_entry.delete(0, END)
    try:
        output_entry.insert(0, int(input_entry.get()) ** 2)
    except Exception:
        output_entry.insert(0, "Wrong Input")


output_entry.delete(0, END)  # Shouldn't show trailing zero when starting the GUI
input_entry.delete(0, END)  # Shouldn't show trailing zero when starting the GUI
input_var.trace("w", key_pressed)
result_var.trace("w", key_pressed)

app.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image: Correct output]

**Error handling:**

[image: Error handling]

Comment: Am very grateful milanbazs,

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this out

You can use Tkinter's trace mechanism to watch the variables associated with your Entry widgets. Whenever the Entry values change the Entry will automatically update.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

app=Tk()
app.geometry("400x350")

var1= tk.IntVar()
ent_lbl=Label(app, text="NUMBER: ", padx=3, pady=3)
ent_lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
entry = tk.Entry(width=15,textvariable=var1)
entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)

result = tk.IntVar()
ans_lbl=Label(app, text="SQUARE: ", padx=3, pady=3)
ans_lbl.grid(column=0, row=20)
ans_txt=tk.Entry(app, width=15,textvariable=result)
ans_txt.grid(column=1, row=20)


def keyPressed(name, index, mode):
    #key = entry.get(event.char)
    key=entry.get()
    if key.isdigit():
        ans_txt.delete(0, END)
        ans_txt.insert(0,int(key)**2)
        print(key, " success")
    else:
        print("fail")

var1.trace('w', keyPressed)
result.trace('w', keyPressed)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Am very grateful for all of you who took your humble time to give me the insight of how to handle the task. Finally through your effort, I was successful to implement what I was building. Hoping to learn from you in future again.